# Import a profile data

Tags: users

I`m trying to find a way to import the userprofile information of drupal to a external soap server, everytime a user is created, updated or deleted.

I figured out that the rules module should be at the basis for what i want to do.

I also found the [webservice client module](https://drupal.org/project/wsclient) which seems to be able to handle soap requests(don't get it yet how this module exactly works).

But i can't wrap my fingers around on how to use these two things to send the userprofile information in xml to external soap server.

Any idea's, tips, suggestions would be welcome! :)